# React How to create a custom Hook

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-query

I want to return data from a custom hook.

```
import { Spinner } from "../../../shared/feedback/Spinner/Spinner";
import { trpc } from "../../../utils/trpc";

export const useCreateActivity = () => {
  // this returns a campaign array
  const { data: campaigns } = trpc.campaign.getCampaigns.useQuery();

  if (!campaigns) {
    return <Spinner />;
  }

  return {
    campaigns,
  };
};
```

Here I'm calling this hook

```
  const { campaigns } = useCreateActivity();

  const onSubmit = (data: Campaign) => {
    console.log(campaigns);
  };

  console.log("campaigns", campaigns);
```

But as you can see I'm getting this error.
[image]

I don't understand what's going on. It seems pretty simple.

Comment: You're right but how can I return that inside an object like const {campaigns}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the hook can return an Element **or** campaigns:

```
if (!campaigns) {
  return <Spinner />;
}

return {
  campaigns,
};
```

So, when you destructure `campaingns`, the returned value of the hook could be the `<Spinner />` element **or** the campaigns. Typescript does not know which it is, and since the `<Spinner />` has no `campaigns` property you get the error.

You could return just the campaigns from you hook:

```
export const useCreateActivity = () => {
  const {data} = trpc.campaign.getCampaigns.useQuery();
  return data;
};
```

And in your component do the conditional logic, something along this lines (untested, very rough code):

```
  const data = useCreateActivity();

  const onSubmit = () => {
    if (!data) return;
    
    // here you know you will have the campaigns
    const { campaigns } = data
    console.log(campaigns);
  };


  // ...

  if (!data) {
    return <Spinner />;
  }
```

Comment: You're right how I didn't see that.